# How to print the result of a function without using print ()?

Tags: r, cran

I need to print the result of the Tukey test result within my function of my package. However, CRAN replied that I cannot use print () / cat (). If I use message (), the message does not come out in the format I want, as in print ().

```
res.aov <- aov(y ~ x, data= data)
  tukey<-TukeyHSD(res.aov)

print(tukey$`x[, 1]`)
```

With print (), the result comes out as I want it to appear on the console:

```
         diff         lwr        upr      p adj
2-1 0.0188276 0.003123183 0.03453202 0.01922062
```

But with message (), the result looks like this:

```
0.01882759965134230.003123182712210140.03453201659047440.0192206190347084
```

Any suggestions for the result to come out as with print ()? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried using `return( )`.

Comment: Huh, `print(tukey$\`x[, 1]\`)` is `NULL`. What are you hoping to "print"?

Comment: You can do `message(paste0(capture.output(tukey$x), collapse="\n"))`.

Comment: Thanks, Stéphane! It worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `capture.output()` function to save the wanted result from the print function to a variable. Then you properly format the strings and pass it to `message()`. See the example below:

```
> x <- c(a = 1, b = 2)
> print(x)
# a b 
# 1 2 
> msg <- capture.output(print(x))
> message(paste(msg, collapse = "\n"))
# a b 
# 1 2
```

Comment: Thanks, Freguglia! It worked! It was the same suggestion from Stéphane! Thanks!!!